# User cannot see a directory in /var/www, thought the directory is there

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, ls

I'd like to create a repository folder that can be accessed by cpanel user. Let say I create a directory in `/var/www/webassets`, and set the access to 777.

I can see the folder using ll command as root user: `ll /var/www/webassets`.

But the folder is invisible to cpanel user. If I run `ll` as cpanel user, I got message that the directory is not there:

`ls: cannot access /var/www/webassets: No such file or directory`

What should I do to makes the directory is accessible by cpanel user?

Edit:

I have run ls on several folder, and this is the result:

```
[root@cpanel ~]# ls -ld / /var /var/www/ /var/www/webassets/
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root     root 4096 Oct  5 20:27 /
drwxr-xr-x. 25 root     root 4096 Sep 29 02:01 /var
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root     root   83 Oct  5 18:49 /var/www/
drwxrwxrwx+  2 plain019 berl   10 Oct  5 09:41 /var/www/webassets/
```

Edit:

Please just ignore this question. I managed to use the /opt folder. I put the directory webassets to /opt, then regular user can access it.

Thanks for replying

Comment: Cpanel is a commercial, paid product, I would browse their forums.

Comment: So you create a directory in `/usr/local` and then complain that the directory is not in `/var/www`?

Comment: sorry, I was typo. I just made correction. thanks for pointing it out. I know that cpanel is commercial, but I was wondering if this is not related to cpanel. If I create a new user using useradd, the new user also cannot see the folder.

Comment: As the cpanel user please run `id`. As your root user please run `ls -ld / /var /var/www /var/www/webassets`. Results of both into your question, please. I would imagine there's a disjoint between the uid/gid of your cpanel user and the permissions available down the tree to the `webassets` directory.

Comment: @roaima a chroot, perhaps?

Comment: There is no need to set 777 permissions anywhere. It can be accessible by others with 755 permissions.

Comment: The `+` in your `ls` output suggests *extended ACLs*, you can manage them using `getfacl`/`setfacl`.

Answer (score 0):

`ls: cannot access /var/www/webassets: No such file or directory`

user `cpanel` doesn't have read or execute access on `/var/www`. check permissions, then add user to relevant group.